# Elastic Beanstalk local environment (with Docker) connection refused

Tags: python, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Problem**

I'm building a Python Flask application and deploying it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Trying to debug the app locally using

```
➜  app git:(master) eb local run
```

It works because the console shows the app to be running. And the following commands also give output that I expect to be correct.

```
➜  app git:(master) docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
251b42afa3df        5aebd9e634c4        "python application.p"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   00394e8605902e1b3f216f4df8b5fec348f4b44f

➜  app git:(master) eb local status
Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.0 running Docker 1.11.2
Container name: 00394e8605902e1b3f216f4df8b5fec348f4b44f
Container ip: 127.0.0.1
Container running: True
Exposed host port(s): 8000
Full local URL(s): 127.0.0.1:8000
```

However, I can not access the app through the browser.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Also with `wget`,

```
➜  app git:(master) wget 127.0.0.1:8000
--2017-01-07 11:46:54--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... failed: Connection refused.
```

**Details**

I would also like to note that when I deploy to the server with `eb deploy`, the app works fine and is accessible through the browser.

```
➜  app git:(master) eb status
Environment details for: app-env
  Application name: app
  Region: ap-southeast-2
  Deployed Version: app-0eca-170107_111723
  Environment ID: e-7tksmeuhun
  Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.0 running Docker 1.11.2
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: --snip--.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2017-01-07 00:18:27.647000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
```

I'd also like to note that running the container like the following also works and is accessible locally.

```
➜  app git:(master) docker run -p 8000:8000 app
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 166-499-205
```

My `Dockerrun.aws.json` looks like this. To be honest, I don't really know what this is supposed to do entirely.

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "ContainerDirectory": "/var/app",
            "HostDirectory": "/var/app"
        }
    ],
    "Logging": "/var/eb_log"
}
```

If there are any other details that are useful to debugging this, then let me know - I can provide. Cheers in advance.